# Actualizar registro de la tabla empleados y la tabla sucursal

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, plsql

quiero actualizar dos registros de tablas relacionadas por una parte esta la tabla empleados que tiene la columna domicilio y la clave primaria codigoCiudad y luego esta la tabla sucursal que tiene la columna ciudad, la tablas tienen más columnas pero para que no sea más lio,
entonces quiero actualizar esas dos tablas, pero no entiendo mucho el update, intente hacer esto pero sin exito

```
update  (SELECT 
            empleados.domicilio,
            sucursal.ciudad 
        FROM empleados_pruebas_jj empleados
        RIGHT JOIN sucursales_pruebas_jj sucursal 
        ON empleados.codigosucursal = sucursal.codigo)
set empleados.domicilio='Avenida Principes de España',
            sucursal.ciudad='Santa Cruz de Tenerife' 
     where empleados.documento='23333333' and sucursal.ciudad='Cordoba'
```

Answer (score 0):

No se si he entendido bien la pregunta, ¿puede ser esto lo que quieres hacer?

update empleados_pruebas
set domicilio  = 'Avenida Principes de España'
where documento = '23333333' and
codigosucursal in (select codigo from sucursales_pruebas
where ciudad = 'Cordoba')

Un consejo, te ahorraras errores si insertas y consultas siempre con valores en mayusculas ..

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).